# Returning nested promises to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS application and I think I have an issue with returning from inside a nested Promise.

As below, the `getToken` function is working. It calls another function to retrieve a password. After this, it uses the password value when making a GET call.

We then successfully get a token and we print the `body` to the console. This works.

However, I now have the challenge of passing the value of `body` which is my token, to another method for later consumption. `printBodyValue` currently fails and fails with an 'undefined' error.

How can I pass the value from deep inside `getToken` to `printBodyValue`

```
getToken: function() {
   module.exports.readCredentialPassword()
 .then(result => {
     var request = require('request-promise');
     var passwd = result;
     var basicAuthData = "Basic " + (new Buffer("fooUser" + ":" + passwd).toString("base64"));
     var options = {
        method: "GET",
        uri: ("http://localhost:8001/service/verify"),
        followRedirects: true,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": basicAuthData
        }
     };
     return request(options)
       .then(function (body) {
         console.log("Token value is: ", body);
         return body;
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
         console.log("Oops! ", err);
       });
   });
}

printBodyValue: function() {
   module.exports.getToken().then(function(body) {
    console.log("Token value from printBodyValue is: \n", body);
   });
}
```

Comment: not look inside the code, but if you format it correctly,  `getToken` doesn't return anything,

Answer (score 1):

In `getToken`, instead of using the nested promise anti-pattern, chain your promises instead, and return the final promise, so that you can then consume the promise and use its resolved value:

(also, since you're using ES6, prefer `const` over `var`)

```
getToken: function() {
  return module.exports.readCredentialPassword()
    .then(result => {
      const request = require('request-promise');
      const passwd = result;
      const basicAuthData = "Basic " + (new Buffer("fooUser" + ":" + passwd).toString("base64"));
      module.exports.log("Sending Request: ", jenkinsCrumbURL);
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
        uri: ("http://localhost:8001/service/verify"),
        followRedirects: true,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": basicAuthData
        }
      };
      return request(options);
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      console.log("Token value is: ", body);
      // the return value below
      // will be the final result of the resolution of
      // `module.exports.readCredentialPassword`, barring errors:
      return body;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Oops! ", err);
    });
}

printBodyValue: function() {
  module.exports.getToken().then(function(body) {
    console.log("Token value from printBodyValue is: \n", body);
  });
}
```